Why python scheduler library shows an error while calling every() function?
I'm getting an error while running this code. it shows that schedule library does not have a function called every(). I have tried to resolve the issue by upgrading the schedule library, but still problem persists.
def schedule_email_notification(event_title, email, date, time_to_send, location, notes):
    def job():
        subject = f"Reminder : {event_title}"
        body = f"Event '{event_title} is scheduled at {location}. \n\nDetails:\n{notes}"
        send_email(subject, body, email)
    date_time_str = f"{date} {time_to_send}"
    event_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    schedule_time = event_datetime.strftime('%h:%M')
    schedule.every().day.at(schedule_time).do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


Does anyone have any other suggestions other than schedule?

What's the error ? Please edit your question and share to complete traceback.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you imported the scheduler or the schedule library?
